# Vimeo not running in UIWebView on iOS 9

Tags: uiwebview, vimeo, ios9

I have a UIWebView embedded within a UIScrollView displaying a Vimeo video:

```
vimeoView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];    
NSMutableString *html = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:1] ;
                        [html appendString:@"<html><head>"];
                        [html appendString:@"<style type=\"text/css\">"];
                        [html appendString:@"body {"];
                        [html appendString:@"background-color: transparent;"];
                        [html appendString:@"color: white;"];
                        [html appendString:@"}"];
                        [html appendString:@"</style>"];
                        [html appendString:@"</head><body style=\"margin:0\">"];
                        [html appendString:@"<iframe src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/%@?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&badge=0&loop=1\" width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>"];
                        [html appendString:@"</body></html>"];

                        NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:html, videoID, vimeoView.frame.size.width, vimeoView.frame.size.height];

                        [vimeoView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://vimeo.com"]];
```

This code is compiled using Xcode 7 and distributed via the App Store (in beta mode, of course). The app runs fine on iOS 8, but on iOS 9 it hangs at 0s after it launches full screen.

Anyone out there got it working on iOS 9? I want to avoid using the Exception for HTTPS switch (or at least use just a narrow exception for specified servers). FWIW, NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = YES doesn't fix this problem anyway.

Comment: I've encountered similar problem and `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` does not work as well, but I temporarily solved it by passing nil to baseURL, can you have a try?

Comment: I've encountered this same issue trying to play a Vimeo video on iOS9 - Vimeo displays the message "Blast! This video can't be played with your current setup." Videos have been playing without issues on iOS7 and iOS8. FYI, I am already passing 'nil' to the baseURL: parameter and it is 
generating this result.

Comment: @DerekLee looks like you have the problem I had. It appears to be a problem with Vimeo's old CDN. Try this video in your app: https://vimeo.com/139107494. That video worked for me. You can then ask Vimeo if they'll move your video(s) to their new CDN. They never replied to me about when all their videos would be moved.

Comment: Thanks @Richard! I tried the video you suggested that is on the new CDN and it is behaving just like the other videos that I have: pressing the play button shows the progress indicator animating as if the video is loading, but it never plays. But if I press pause, and then play again, it does start to play. My videos appear to be doing the same thing - they don't play the first time, but after hitting the button 2-3x they do start to play. Better than not working at all, but still not the expected user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the response I received from Vimeo support:

> We’re in the process of migrating between CDNs so I’m curious if that has anything to do with what you’re seeing.
>
> For example, can you try this video: https://vimeo.com/76979871, which is located on our older CDN;
>
> and this video: https://vimeo.com/139107494, located on our newer CDN.

For me, this worked in that the video on the newer CDN worked fine in my app, the video on the older CDN did not. However, I have not heard back on whether/when old CDN videos will be migrated to the new CDN.

----- Update from Vimeo support 9/22:

Webviews in iOS 9 will not load insecure content (HTTP) over a secure connection (HTTPS). When playing back older videos, which are hosted on our older CDN, some content is still served over HTTP. More recently uploaded videos have all their assets served over HTTPS, and will play back fine in iOS 9 webviews.

Does your app feature videos only from your Vimeo account, or does it also display videos from others? If you’re only using your own videos in your app, I recommend uploading those videos again; they should automatically go to our newer CDN where all the assets are served over HTTPS.

We’re in the process of moving videos from our older CDN onto our newer CDNs, but there’s no public timeframe for how long this will take.

Comment: I opened a topic on the Vimeo forum about this a couple of days ago (https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:277009#comment_13777904) and just got a response from a staff member: "This is because the actual video segments aren't served securely. Unfortunately, iOS 9 won't load any insecure stuff over secure. This is something we're still currently testing and hope to have it resolved in the near future."

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    NSURLRequest* request = [webView request];
    NSString *host = [request.URL host];

    if ([host isEqualToString:@"player.vimeo.com"]){
        NSString *js = @"document.querySelector('.play').click();";
        [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
    }
}
```